# TFS programmatically load file by path hitting DownloadTicketValidationException

Tags: c#, tfs

### Overview / TLDR

I'm facing a situation in which I have a database table of filepaths from TFS and need to programmatically download each file to parse them line by line, looking for specific snippets of code. Currently, I am using VersionControlServer.DownloadFileByUrl(filePath) to get a filestream, but I am facing "DownloadTicketValidationException:TF15006: The request file ID was missing or empty."

I would like to know either:

A.) How do I retrieve and set this Request File ID in order to retrieve this file?

B.) Is there another means of retrieving said file given only the url that does not run into this issue?

### Details

```cs
//Omitted wrapping try-catch block for brevity
private static string GetFileAsString(ref VersionControlServer server, string filePath)
{
    string content;
    using (var fileStream = server.DownloadFileByUrl(filePath))
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream); // Throws  DownloadTicketValidationException:TF15006: The request file ID was missing or empty.
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray())))
            {
                content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

The filepath is formatted with `$"{serverURL}:8080/tfs/{collectionName}/{filepath.TrimStart('$', '/')}"`which appears to be a valid path (I can verify it in Team Foundation Explorer).

the VersionControlServer is opened with:

```cs
...
using (var teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new  Uri(collectionUrl)))
{
    teamProjectCollection.ClientCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(); // Uses my credentials when running under VS, which should have access.
    var versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
...
```

Comment: How about use local path for the file in the workspace? Would you see the same error?

Comment: @cece, interestingly, it throws a "TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException:TF30063: You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/8.5." - I can perform a get on that file via VS with no issue. I'm now searching for documentation on permissions needed for that call. Thanks! While it's not a solution, it gives me a new angle to explore.

Comment: How about using tf get command to get file: https://www.visualstudio.com/ko-kr/docs/tfvc/get-command

Comment: @Cece-MSFT, I can perform a get without issue, but that doesn't solve the code problem at hand - I'm pulling files into memory inorder to parse and find select lines; I don't have enough space to write the entire file tree to a local hard drive.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT, Eddies answer (accepted) solved my problem - I can't download the file directly from serverbut instead first have to get a TFS item and then call its DownloadFile method. This solves my issue, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://tfscollectionurl/";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(url));
            VersionControlServer vcs = ttpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            Item item = vcs.GetItem("$/Path/of/file");
            var filestream = item.DownloadFile();
            string content;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                filestream.CopyTo(memoryStream); // Throws  DownloadTicketValidationException:TF15006: The request file ID was missing or empty.
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray())))
                {
                    content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(content);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: thank you, that did it. I apparently cannot directly get the file from path, but rather have to get the Item from that path and then load the file from the Item. Answer accepted.